# How to create a self-signed (or signed by own CA) SSL certificate for IP address that pass Chrome requirements

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate

How to create self-signed (or signed by own CA) SSL certificate that can be trusted by Chrome (after adding CA certificate to local machine).

Certificate must be valid for local network IPs, localhost and multiple domains

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Prepare config files for creating certificates non-interactivelly (without prompts)

`CA.cnf` →

```
[ req ]
prompt = no
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name

[ req_distinguished_name ]
C = US
ST = Localzone     
L = localhost    
O = Certificate Authority Local Center
OU = Develop      
CN = develop.localhost.localdomain
emailAddress = root@localhost.localdomain
```

`localhost.cnf` →

```
[req]
default_bits  = 2048
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions = req_ext
x509_extensions = v3_req
prompt = no

[req_distinguished_name]
countryName = US
stateOrProvinceName = Localzone
localityName = Localhost
organizationName = Certificate signed by my CA
commonName = localhost.localdomain

[req_ext]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[v3_req]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
IP.1 = 127.0.0.1
IP.2 = 127.0.0.2
IP.3 = 127.0.0.3
IP.4 = 192.168.0.1
IP.5 = 192.168.0.2
IP.6 = 192.168.0.3
DNS.1 = localhost
DNS.2 = localhost.localdomain
DNS.3 = dev.local
```

2. Generate a CA private key and Certificate (valid for 5 years)

```
openssl req -nodes -new -x509 -keyout CA_key.pem -out CA_cert.pem -days 1825 -config CA.cnf
```

3. Generate web server secret key and CSR

```
openssl req -sha256 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout localhost_key.pem -out localhost.csr -config localhost.cnf
```

4. Create certificate and sign it by own certificate authority ([valid 1 year](https://www.certisur.com/en/google-chrome-limits-the-validity-of-ssl-certificates-to-one-year/))

```
openssl x509 -req -days 398 -in localhost.csr -CA CA_cert.pem -CAkey CA_key.pem -CAcreateserial -out localhost_cert.pem -extensions req_ext -extfile localhost.cnf
```

5. Profit

Output files will be:

- `CA.cnf` → OpenSSL CA config file. May be deleted after certificate creation process.
- `CA_cert.pem` → [Certificate Authority] certificate. This certificate must be added to the browser local authority storage to make trust all certificates that created with using this CA.
- `CA_cert.srl` → Random serial number. May be deleted after certificate creation process.
- `CA_key.pem` → Must be used when creating new [localhost] certificate. May be deleted after certificate creation process (if you do not plan reuse it and CA_cert.pem).
- `localhost.cnf` → OpenSSL SSL certificate config file. May be deleted after certificate creation process.
- `localhost.csr` → Certificate Signing Request. May be deleted after certificate creation process.
- `localhost_cert.pem` → SSL certificate. **Must be installed at WEB server**.
- `localhost_key.pem` → Secret key. **Must be installed at WEB server**.

SSL Certificate alternative names can be checked by

```
openssl x509 -noout -text -in localhost_cert.pem | grep 'X509v3 Subject Alternative Name' -A 1
```

Comment: That's not self-signed, which has a strict technical meaning of 'having issuer identical to subject and signed using the subject's own keypair'. But you probably don't actually need self-signed, just 'created by me all alone' and this is fine for that. It _is_ duplicate of dozens of other Qs (and the man pages) but since you didn't read them, most likely other people won't read yours either.

Comment: `That's not self-signed` → good point. Updated. `It is duplicate of dozens of other Qs`  → It is groups dozens of Qs. 1. How to use alternative names, 2. How to create certificate with own CA, 3. How to set ip addresses as alt names, 4. It is shorter (some openssl commands grouped into one), 5. Here is explanation why expiration time is 398 days only, 6. How to create certificate automatically without prompts. I didn't see all this information in one place. `people won't read yours either` → not a big deal

Comment: @rzlvmp i just read it...this just saved my ass, thanks!