# Connecting two containers directly in Docker via SSL

Tags: docker, ssl

This is for my local docker development. I have two docker hosts and I'm using traefik's reverse proxy to pull them up in browser. One of the hosts is an api which I need to communicate via https calls. The container I'm trying to connect to has the following params:

```
version: "3.8"

networks:
  local-proxy:
    external: true
  internal:
    external: false

services:
    web:
        build:
            context: ./docker/bin/php
        container_name: "app-web"
        expose:
            - "80"
            - "443"
        networks:
            - internal
            - local-proxy
```

I'm able to connect to it via curl when the call is made via non-ssl (http).

curl http://app-web (200 response)

I need to be able to connect via https, in order to keep everything like it's running in production, however it keeps throwing `Failed to connect to app-web port 443: Connection refused`

Is it possible at all to connect via 443 port from one container to another?

Note: These containers are never deployed to production. They are just for local dev.

Comment: *docker host* is a term for the host machine where docker command and daemon is installed. *docker container* is a term for the running docker image process. do you really mean *docker host*?

Comment: 1. create [own certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66558788/how-to-create-a-self-signed-or-signed-by-own-ca-ssl-certificate-for-ip-address) for `app-web`, 2. add this certificate (or CA certificate) as trusted to client container, 3. set `app-web` certificate to PHP web server, 4. profit. Or just run `curl` with `--insecure` options. If you don't want to set certificate at client side

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is the stuff running in `app-web` listening on port 443?

Comment: @Lei Yang, Docker host as in two docker-compose builds on local host which can communicate. I'm out of ideas on how to actually call that.

Comment: @NicoHaase, I've tried generating SSL on app-web container, however I'm not sure I'm doing it right. I feel like this had to be done by numerous devs in the past, but for the life of me I can find a single working example.

Comment: Face this issue for 2 hours, I know there will be the way but I can't find any guidelines.